# iOS7 Sprite Kit can I archive the entire scene and use it as a save game?

Tags: ios, save, sprite-kit, sknode, skscene

I'm looking at the `userData` property of SKNode and noticed this statement:

> Sprite Kit does not do anything with the data stored in the node.
>   However, the data is archived when the node is archived.

This got me thinking - is it possible to implement a single save game functionality by archiving the scene and all of it's dependents/controllers?

I'm trying to understand if there's some magical [archive] message that I can send to the scene or scene view to remove the need for writing custom data structures to store save game.

Answer (score 5):

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000950-SW2) out. From the SpriteKit Programming Guide:

> Because all Sprite Kit classes support archiving, you can simply
>   create archives of important Sprite Kit objects and then include these
>   archives in your game. For example, you might:
>
> - Store a game level as an archive of a scene node. This archive    includes the scene, all of its descendants in the node tree, and all
>     of their connected physics bodies, joints, and actions.
> - Store individual archives for specific pre-configured nodes, such a    node for each monster. Then, when a new monster needs to be created,
>     you load it from the archive.
> - Store saved games as a scene archive.